# Cartopy slow rendering with non orthographic projection

Tags: rendering, cartopy

I'm using Cartopy to visualize functions in spherical coordinates. I'm currently using Cartopy's development version (installed via `pip git+...`) and using `geos` and `proj` from Conda. I'm also using Shapely's development version (with `pip install --no-binary :all: git+https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely.git`)

My problem is that when I render plots with a non-Orthographic projection, the library takes a significant amount of time to generate the image compared to an Orthographic projection. Here there is a minimal example:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import time

# Data
# Notice: we can use either phi ∈ [-180, 180] OR phi ∈ [0, 360]
phi = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
lat = np.linspace(-np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, 200)
# NOTICE: that PI is defined in the -z direction
theta = (lat + np.pi / 2)[::-1]
data = np.zeros((len(theta), len(phi)), dtype=np.float64)
for j, Th in enumerate(theta):
    for i, Ph in enumerate(phi):
        data[j, i] = Ph  # plot by longitude
```

Orthographic (very fast):

```
t = time.time()
# Set up figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4))
inclination = 50  # degrees from pole
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Orthographic(0, 90 - inclination))

vlim = np.max(np.abs(data))
p = ax.pcolormesh(phi * 180 / np.pi, lat * 180 / np.pi,
                  data,
                  transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                  cmap='RdBu',vmin=0, vmax=vlim)
ax.autoscale_view()
gl = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=False)
plt.colorbar(p)
plt.show()
print(time.time() - t)
# 0.1487586498260498
```

Non-orthographic (super slow):

```
t = time.time()
# Set up figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.InterruptedGoodeHomolosine())

vlim = np.max(np.abs(data))
p = ax.pcolormesh(phi * 180 / np.pi, lat * 180 / np.pi,
                  data,
                  transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                  cmap='RdBu',vmin=0, vmax=vlim)
ax.autoscale_view()
gl = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=False)
plt.colorbar(p)
plt.show()
print(time.time() - t)
# 100.34914875030518
```

I'm not sure if this is due to Cartopy's version or maybe `geos`, `proj` or `shapely` which Cartopy's depends on. I remember with an older version of Cartopy the rendering was not that slow.

Comment: Somehow, using `shading='flat'` in `pcolormesh` solves the rendering speed problem, although I get a warning: `MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: shading='flat' when X and Y have the same dimensions as C is deprecated since 3.3.  Either specify the corners of the quadrilaterals with X and Y, or pass shading='auto', 'nearest' or 'gouraud', or set rcParams['pcolor.shading'].`. However, using `shading='gouraud'` fails with `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 20000 into shape (199,99)`

Comment: Did you try with `pcolorfast` instead of `pcolormesh`? With orthographic projections it can sometimes make a huge difference (but I never tried with non-orthographic).

Comment: I wasn't aware of that function, thanks. However it seems limited: "It supports only flat shading (no outlines)". Which is the same if I use `flat` shading in `pcolormesh`.

Comment: Indeed, `pcolorfast` has limited features compared with `pcolormesh`; this is probably why it can go really fast.